# Обработать JSON строку по POST запросу

Tags: php, json

Из Android приложения делаю POST запрос с JSON строкой на свой сервер(php). Как на сервере мне обработать JSON? Можно какой-то пример или ссылку?!

Comment: Ссылку/пример на что?

Comment: Если кратко, `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = $_POST['ключ'];
$arr = json_decode($json, true); // Вы получаете ассоциативный массив, в котором ключи есть ключи объекта. Т.е. массив будет повторять структуру Вашего json.
```

Вот пример.

```
<?php 
$json = '{"test":[{"a": "aaa", "b": "bbb"},{"a": "AAA", "b": "BBB"}]}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($arr['test'] as $value)
{
echo $value["a"] . " ";
echo $value["b"] . " ";
}
?>
```

Comment: Обычно, если в Post запросе передаётся json, он не является полем `form-urlencoded`, а передаётся целиком в теле запроса с `Content-type: application/json`. Хотя, всякое бывает.

Comment: Если json передается в теле, то он будет строкой в переменной $_POST

Comment: Данный способ будет эквивалентен file_get_contents?